# Set up QGIS Server on Windows 7?

Tags: qgis-server, windows-7

I want to share QGIS files and maps which are made by me, to some of my friends through a server. Then I want to know:

1. how to establish a server and network to upload QGIS maps and files
2. how to upload maps and QGIS files

I refer to the QGIS server instructions, but I couldn't get any favorable result. I want simply understandable instructions.

My system is **Windows 7**

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered QGIS Cloud http://qgiscloud.com/? It's beta but free and you don't have to bother setting up your own server.

Otherwise, follow these instructions:
http://underdark.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/